# Is it possible to do this?. Taking into account that the order table has in the status field the value 10

Tags: laravel

```
$status = [10 => 'Pendiente',20 => 'Pagada',30 => 'Cancelada'];
$orders = DB::table('order')->join('status', 'order.status', '=', $status)->get();
```

Comment: Please expand your question. What are you trying to do? What is your problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to have descriptions for the status codes? If so you can do it client side either with model accessors or just do `map` on a result set collection just you fetch with the query builder.